# How to add trace to plotly scatter plot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, scatter-plot

```
 p <- plot_ly(data = bData,  x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal,  type = 'scatter', mode='markers',  
               symbol = ~Sym,  symbols = c('circle-open','x-open','diamond-open','square-open') ,
               text = ~paste(bData$Security,bData$Crncy, bData$YTM, bData$DM,sep = "<br>") ,hoverinfo = 'text'
         )
```

Above code produces this plot.

[image]

Now to this chart I want to add a trace with scatter plot with color depending on Currency column.
I tried this but it produces combination of two field as the legend.

Basically I want to classify the plot based on currency type but also add overlay or trace based on column SYM as the symbol.

```
  p <- plot_ly(data = bData,  x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal,  type = 'scatter', mode='markers',  
               symbol = ~Sym,  symbols = c('circle-open','x-open','diamond-open','square-open') ,
               text = ~paste(bData$Security,bData$Crncy, bData$YTM, bData$DM,sep = "<br>") ,hoverinfo = 'text'
         ) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal , color=~Crncy)
```

[image]

data:

```
bData <- structure(list(Crncy = structure(c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 9L,
7L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 9L,
9L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 9L,
9L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 9L,
9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("AUD",
"CAD", "CHF", "COP", "EUR", "GBP", "JPY", "PEN", "USD", "ZAR"
), class = "factor"), `Maturity Date` = structure(c(20772, 19689,
18969, 18969, 20815, 20119, 20865, 20864, 20134, 20873, 20873,
20887, 20011, 20897, 20162, 19797, 20908, 20908, 20923, 19841,
19107, 19107, 20941, 20935, 20936, 20936, 20953, 20049, 19138,
19860, 21005, 21027, 19562, 19562, 21014, 19222, 21047, 19950,
19264, 19285, 19292, 19292, 19323, 19382, 19381, 20000, 19404,
20176, 19437, 19875, 19875, 19508, 20635, 19555, 19555, 20658,
19038, 19628, 18946, 19745, 19746, 19021, 19042, 19042, 20545,
20623, 19047, 19412, 19415, 20178, 20178, 19611, 19807, 20168,
20551, 20640, 20957, 20223, 19858, 19692, 19158, 20258, 19720,
20269, 20999, 20999, 20290, 20278, 20300, 20300, 21029, 19753,
20318, 20328, 20423, 20120, 20223, 20240, 19335, 20594, 19510,
19905, 20073, 20347, 20392, 18897, 20962, 20994, 21009, 21043,
19287, 19505, 18899, 19006, 19081, 19323, 19373, 19203, 19417,
19415, 19430, 19469, 19492, 19527, 19599, 20344, 19638, 19655,
19675, 19688, 20068, 19711, 19780, 19803, 19838, 19865, 19892,
19890, 19940, 19962, 20706, 20011, 18927, 20041, 18949, 20777,
20116, 20145, 19041, 20156, 20177, 20174, 20173, 20205, 20208,
20235, 20248, 20249, 19523, 20521, 20588, 20574, 20465, 20482,
19400, 20588, 21021, 20649, 20389, 20409, 19950, 19600, 19601,
20346, 19658, 20747, 19657, 19656, 19657, 20307, 20347, 19259,
20087, 20810, 20077, 19349, 20118, 20483, 20112, 20109, 19392,
19594, 20144, 21056, 19407, 20749, 20573, 19296, 19300, 19300,
19310, 20041, 19346, 20907, 19976, 20744, 20202, 19132, 19132,
19132), class = "Date"), Sym = structure(c(4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L,
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L,
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L,
1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L,
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L,
3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L,
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L,
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L,
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L,
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L,
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L,
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Axe",
"Axe, Owned", "None", "Owned"), class = "factor"), YVal = c(20,
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,
37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52,
53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68,
69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100,
101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113,
114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126,
127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139,
140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152,
153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165,
166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178,
179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191,
192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204,
205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217,
218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-210L))
```

Comment: Please add some dummy data to reproduce the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is this what you are looking for? (I have used `split` from `plotly`):

```
library(plotly)
#Code
plot_ly(data = bData,  x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal,  type = 'scatter', mode='markers',  
        symbol = ~Sym,  symbols = c('circle-open','x-open','diamond-open','square-open') ,
        split = ~Crncy,
        text = ~paste(bData$Security,bData$Crncy, bData$YTM, bData$DM,sep = "<br>") ,
        hoverinfo = 'text')
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:** Here somo other options for OP:

```
#Option 1
plot_ly(data = bData,  x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal,  type = 'scatter', mode='markers',  
        symbol = ~Sym,  symbols = c('circle-open','x-open','diamond-open','square-open') ,
        text = ~paste(bData$Security,bData$Crncy, bData$YTM, bData$DM,sep = "<br>") ,
        hoverinfo = 'text',legendgroup = 'group1'
) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal , symbol=~Crncy,legendgroup = 'group2')
```

Output:

[image]

Option 2:

```
#Option 2
plot_ly(bData, x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal,  type = 'scatter', mode='markers',
               legendgroup = 'group1',color = ~Sym) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~YVal, legendgroup = 'group2',type = 'scatter', mode='markers',
            color=~Crncy)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it produces the product of two columns i.e. Currency x Sym. I want to plot them separately. And this plot is similar to what I had tried and posted in the qquestion.

Comment: @AriKari So what you want is two different legends?

Comment: Yes. Currency and Sym should be separate. Basically final plot should show what it would look like if we were to superimpose the two scatter plots with currency and symbol separately plotted.

Comment: @AriKari Let me add a proxy for your issue! I believe I have what you want!

Comment: @AriKari I have added two options for you. I hope any of them can be useful !!!

Comment: Is it not possible to have symbols for the Axe, Owned, ... and colored dots for currency?

Comment: @AriKari I believe that is the main issue why you couldn't get your initial plots displayed correctly.